# The differentiability of the function of two variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I have a function $f(x, y)$ which is known to be defined at some neighbourhood of $(0, 0)$ and continuous at $(0, 0).$ I need to prove that the function $g(x, y) = xyf(x, y)$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$

> According to the sufficient condition of differentiability, partial derivatives of $g(x, y)$ should be continuous in some neighbourhood of $(0, 0)$. Let's consider these derivatives: $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = yf(x, y) + xy\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = xf(x, y) + xy\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.

How can we prove that these derivatives are continuous at some neighbourhood of $(0, 0)$, using the fact that $f(x, y)$ is continuous at $(0, 0)$? 
Thanks in advance for any hints!

Comment: $f$ need not have partial derivatives.

Comment: @Jochen Oh, but it **has to**. They may not be continuous at some point necessarily and still the function may be differentiable there, but without one of the partial derivatives at that point the function cannot be differentiable at all.

Comment: As you wrote it, if some other condition isn't given or if it is not given the partial derivatives of $\;f\;$ at the origin **exist**, I can't see how you're going to prove *even* that the partial derivatives of $\;g\;$ at the origin exist, let alone to prove they are continuous there...

Comment: @DonAntonio I can assume that there is a typo in my textbook, but if so, I need to think up a counter example

Comment: You will not be able to show continuity of the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ because those partial derivatives need not exist in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$

Comment: @zhw. I understand. But I don't know other ways to prove differentiability except verifying the feasibility of the sufficient condition...

Comment: Sure you do. You know the definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: It might be easier to prove a stronger result. Suppose $g$ is defined in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ with $g(0,0)=0.$ If $g(x,y) =o((x^2+y^2)^{1/2})$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0),$ then $Dg(0,0)=0.$

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. Thus the whole proof must be like: $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{g(x, y)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = \lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{xyf(x, y)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = \lim_{r \to 0} r\cos \phi \sin \phi f(r \cos \phi, r \sin \phi) = 0$ because of the continuity of $f(x, y)$ (I substituted $x = r\cos \phi, y = r\sin \phi$) hence $g(x, y) = o(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}), (x, y) \to (0, 0)$, hence at the neighbourhood of $(0, 0)$ $g(x, y)$ can be represented as $g(x, y) = g(0, 0) + Ax + By + o(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$ hence it's differentiable at $(0, 0)$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, but it would be good to say what $A,B$ are in this case.

Comment: they are some numbers, which are not depend on $x, y$

Comment: In fact $A=B=0$ here. That's a key to proving the result I mentioned.

Comment: why 0? We want $g(x, y)$ to be $o(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}), (x, y) \to (0, 0)$ and since $Ax \to 0, x \to 0 \forall \ A, $ $By \to 0, y \to 0 \forall \ B$ hence $g(x, y) = o(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}), (x, y) \to (0, 0)$

Comment: No, no, you're missing something. If $A\ne 0,$ then $Ax$ is not $o(\sqrt { x^2+y^2}).$

Comment: Yes, really, I've understood. Thank you once more